# A mnemonic for compatibility equations (Gauss-Mainardi-Codazzi equations)

Tags: differential-geometry

I learn how to deduce the Gauss-Mainardi-Codazzi equations, but I don't want to spend time deducing that on my exams. There's a mnemonic for memorize the equations below?
$$(\Gamma_{12}^2)_u-(\Gamma_{11}^2)_v+\Gamma_{12}^1\Gamma_{11}^2+\Gamma_{12}^2\Gamma_{12}^2+\Gamma_{11}^2\Gamma_{22}^2+\Gamma_{11}^1\Gamma_{12}^2=-EK;$$
$$(\Gamma_{12}^1)_u-(\Gamma_{11}^1)_v+\Gamma_{12}^2\Gamma_{12}^1-\Gamma_{11}^2\Gamma_{22}^1=FK;$$
$$e_v-f_u=e\Gamma_{12}^1+f(\Gamma_{12}^2-\Gamma_{11}^1)-g\Gamma_{11}^2;$$
$$f_v-g_u=e\Gamma_{22}^1+f(\Gamma_{22}^2-\Gamma_{12}^1)-g\Gamma_{12}^2.$$

Comment: I always provided these equations to my students in my undergraduate differential geometry courses. Memorization is pointless.  (If you ultimately learn how to do differential geometry with differential forms, then the Gauss and Codazzi equations become three simple, easily remembered equations.)

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for the comment.